# jmeter: how to fetch 6 requests in parallel in a transaction controller to simulate real browser

Tags: jmeter

When you record your website using the jmeter "Test Script Recorder", you can set each page to be a transaction.  Say you have 20 pages, each with 100 requests.  you will get 20 transaction controllers, each with 100 sub requests.  The transaction controller has "generate parent sample" which allows you to output the statistics per page, such as min and max times to load the page etc.  You can also add "think time" between transactions, just like a real user reading pages before clicking on next, which are not included in the page load times.

This is perfect except for one critical detail: browsers don't download a pages requests in series, they do 6 in parallel. Thus the times shown are wrong (far too large), and the server load pattern is different (although similar over time given we want to simulate 5k concurrent users)

There is a "parallel controller" plugin, but this is not suitable for two reasons:

1. it does not work with transaction controller, according to the docs.
2. you cant specify how many parallel downloads (e.g. 6) - it will try to download all 100 at the same time.  Manually dividing 100 requests into groups 6 would also not work correctly.

I tried adding a new thread group under the main threadgroup, thinking sub-thread groups could provide this, but it doesn't seem to let you.

Our load tests are predicated on acceptable page load times, which we cant find any way to  simulate.

Any suggestions for hacks/work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

If these 100 requests are for images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc. - you should not be recording them at all and let JMeter download them on its own, the relevant setting lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Requests Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) configuration element:

[image]

See [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) article for more information

Comment: Hi, this does not work unfortunately, as most of the images are loaded from javascript, and javascript is not evaluated by the http sampler.   Therefore we have to resort to recording.  What we are looking for is this same "parallel downloads. Number", but on a controller we can put the recorded samples under.  This does not seem to exist, which is a pretty big limitation for us unfortunately.

Comment: In that case you could go for i.e. [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and download the resources using [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) having 6 threads for single domain (or more if there are different domains) like it's described in the [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) article